# Panda DataFrame reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

Got the following DataFrame:

```
                Body Weight (KG) Exercise 1  Weight (KG)   Exercise 2  \
Date                                                              
17/07/17              77.9      Squat             20.0     Bench Press   

                Weight (KG).1   Exercise 3  Weight (KG).2  
Date                                                 
17/07/17           20.0         Barbell Row           30.0
```

Trying to reshape into a tidy format:

```
Date      Body Weight Exercise     Weight
17/07/17  77.9        Squat        20.0
17/07/17  77.9        Bench Press  20.0
17/07/17  77.9        Barbell Row  30.0
```

Tried using the melt function using

```
pd.melt(df,value_vars=["Exercise 1","Exercise 2","Exercise 3"])
```

resulted in:

```
   variable        value
0  Exercise 1      Squat
1  Exercise 2      Bench Press
2  Exercise 3      Barbell Row
```

how do I get the weights and other columns "lined up" with the correct date and exercise?

Comment: `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` and paste the output here please, it is impossible to copy your df as it is now.

Comment: {'Weight (KG)': {'17/07/17': 20.0}, 'Weight (KG).1': {'17/07/17': 20.0}, 'Weight (KG).2': {'17/07/17': 30.0}, 'Body Weight (KG)': {'17/07/17': 77.900000000000006}, 'Exercise 1': {'17/07/17': 'Squat'}, 'Exercise 2': {'17/07/17': 'Bench Press'}, 'Exercise 3': {'17/07/17': 'Barbell Row'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add `Body Weight (KG)` column to `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then call `DataFrame` constructor with repeating `index` values.

`Notice` - Need pairs `Exercise` and `Weight` in all column without first for correct output

```
df = df.set_index('Body Weight (KG)', append=True)
a = len(df.index)
b = int(len(df.columns) / 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(a * b ,2), 
                  index=df.index.repeat(b), 
                  columns=['Exercise', 'Weight']).reset_index()
print (df)
       Date  Body Weight (KG)     Exercise Weight
0  17/07/17              77.9        Squat     20
1  17/07/17              77.9  Bench Press     20
2  17/07/17              77.9  Barbell Row     30
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what was needed.